# error -varname command not found in the bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I created my first bash script but there is an error `varname command not found` in line 9. 
I suppose I need to echo varname different way?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'please provide disk name'
read varname
sudo file -s /dev/$varname
 if [ "$(sudo file -s /dev/$varname)" = "/dev/$varname: data" ]; then
    sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/$varname
    sudo mkdir /mnt/$varname
    sudo mount /dev/$varname /mnt/$varname
    sudo echo "/dev/$varname /mnt/$varname ext4 defaults,nofail 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
    sudo touch test.txt /mnt/$varname
 else
  echo "wrong disk name"
fi
```

Comment: Unrelated, but running `echo` with `sudo` doesn't allow you to write to `/etc/fstab`. The file is opened for writing by the shell before `sudo` runs.

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that would try to run `varname` as a command.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, but the text is there without $varname

it should be like this  "/dev/$varname /mnt/$varname ext4 defaults,nofail 0 2"

but in the fstab file is  /dev/  /mnt/ ext4 defaults,nofail 0 2

Comment: `varname` doesn't appear to be set at all; I don't see how you would get that result from the code you have shown, unless you don't actually type a disk name.

Comment: thank you for your reply. yes you type disk name from the beginning of the script
echo 'please provide disk name'
read varname

Comment: The output you show indicates `varname` is *not* set, though, so I don't see how the code you show can reproduce any of the behavior you are reporting.

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the script from your post into a new file, run it, and edit your post to include the complete copy-pasted output from your shell including the command you used to run it? Make sure not to make any modifications, and to not type any error messages by hand  (copy-paste only)

Comment: my sudo called a child process, into which a variable without export was not passed.     Fixed by adding export.